# Is there any alternative to use <Link> outside a <Router> with react?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-router-v4

I'm trying to use Link in a component outside the Router in React but i'm getting the error:

> You should not use  outside a `<Router>`

I want to render my App component, that contains all needed subcomponents, and the HeaderIcons components, that must be shown in every page on the top.
the HeaderIcons component contains a Link to a specific Route.

This is the render method in App:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <div>
                <Route onEnter={this.onRouteUpdate.bind(this)} exact path="" component={Configration} />
                <Route onEnter={this.onRouteUpdate.bind(this)} path="/PersonalData" component={Headerlayout} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

onRouteUpdate(routerState) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    sendLocation(routerState.location);
}


ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("content"));
ReactDom.render(<HeaderIcons />, document.getElementById("configuration_icons"));
```

And this is the Link in HeaderIcons:

```
<Link 
    to="/PersonalData"
    className="icon"
    onMouseOver={this.onmouseoverHandler}
    onMouseOut={this.onmouseooutHandler}>
    <img src="/static/images/user.png" alt="User" />
</Link>
```

Is there a way to achieve this with react Router v4?

Comment: you need to restructure the app, put `HeaderIcons` in the App itself, inside `Router`, like this: `<Router><div>< HeaderIcons /> /* all the routes here*/ </div></Router>`. otherwise routing will not work.

Comment: Don't forget to use React.Fragment :)

Comment: Are you importing Link from 'react-router-dom'?

Comment: thanks for the answers. the only way is to restructure the app.
@ravibagul91 yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to follow next approach in structuring your app. (With React-Router)

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


// in render method of your App component

<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="app">
        <HeaderComponentWithLinks> // <- see it under BrowserRouter component
        <div className="content">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/about"  component={AboutPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>  
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now you will not see an error.